# Google Maps detects long click when floating action button pressed and map clicked

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a view with a MapView and FloatingActionButton.
When I click and hold the button and click on map with my other finger, long click is called instead of a click. Why is that and how to fix it?

GMapView.cs

```
public class GMapView : BaseFragment<MapViewModel>, IOnMapReadyCallback
{
    private GoogleMap _googleMap;

    // some more code

    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        _googleMap = googleMap;            
        _googleMap.MapLongClick += _googleMap_MapLongClick;
        _googleMap.MapClick += _googleMap_MapClick;
    }

    private void _googleMap_MapClick(object sender, MapClickEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private async void _googleMap_MapLongClick(object sender, MapLongClickEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

GMapView.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">     
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right">
    <FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/myLocalization"
        local:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_my_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/standard_margin"
        local:MvxBind="Click MyLocationCommand; Allowed IsLocationEnabled" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Which version of MapView in your project? I tested your code and it works fine . In my project , long click event is `_googleMap.LongClick += _googleMap_LongClick;`

Comment: It is a nuget Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps 71.1600.0

Comment: Could you share your sample so that I can test it on my side .

Comment: It is commercial, so I can't. I already see that your event name is different.